# Not able to access file inside assets folder in java

Tags: java, html, grails

I want to open a file inside [assets/cv] folder and i tried using this two method for opening file when clicked in button but it is not working.The file i want to open is .pdf type and it is not downloading the file.

.gsp file

```
<td>
    <a href="C:\\Users\\Ashwin\\businessapp\\src\\main\\webapp\\assets\\cv\\"+"${trainuserLists.cvName}" download>View CV</a>
</td>
```

Another method

```
<td>
    <a href="${application.contextPath}/static/assets/cv/${trainuserLists.cvName}" download>View CV</a>
</td>
```

Comment: This is html not java

Comment: bt it should bt loaded in groovy page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the assetPath method in your gsp like in this example.

`<link href="${assetPath(src: 'manifest.json')}"/>`

The [documentation](http://www.asset-pipeline.com/manual) might give you some pointers too.